# Isolated singularities and identifying them

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve a problem stated as: Identify the isolated singularities of the function f(z) and does it have an isolated singularity at infinity. The function is given by:

$$f(z) = \dfrac{ exp\bigg(\dfrac{1}{1-z}\bigg)}{(exp(z)-1)^2}  $$

Singularities I can see directly is $z=2\pi i k$ and $z=1$ but which type of singularity are these? I'm having quite a hard time with this concept and the difference between isolated and essential singularities so any help that could set me in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Just follow the definitions and see which types of singularities are they.

Comment: Essential singularities are isolated.  There are $3$ kinds of isolated singularities: removable singularities, isolated singularities, and poles.  There are also singularities that aren't isolated, such as branch points and branch cuts.

Comment: Ok from my lecture note I wrote that if f is analytic on domain D except at a point c then c is an isolated singularity. So that would mean that $z=0$ and $z=2\pi i k $ are isolated singularities? I'm still unsured about  $z=1$

Answer (score 1):

The word isolated is pretty clear from context and usage: it is not a cluster point.

This means, there exists an open ball around that point such that it contains no other singularities or problems.

The only difficulty is what "an open ball around infinity" means. This is, in a sense, the complement of an open ball around zero. These are 
$$\{z\mid\left|z\right|>c\}\text{.}$$

Failures of being isolated include cluster points of singularities, and branch cuts. Essential singularities can be isolated.

Comment: Would $z=0$ then fail to be an isolated singularity since $exp(z)$ is periodic i.e a cluster of singularities or is it considered as just one/ the same singularity?

Comment: Directly use the definition! Can you find an open ball around $0$ such that there is only the singularity at $0$ *and no others*?

Comment: Sure but before that I'm still not sure if every period of $exp(z)$ is viewed as the same singularity or unique ones. If they are viewed as the same I would say that it is isolated but if it every period is viewed as an unique singularity I would say it is not an isolated singularity...

Comment: Does $\sin(x)$ have isolated zeros? Yes or no? (If you want singularities: does $\csc(x)$ have isolated poles?)

Comment: I don't know since this is the first problem I'm doing of this kind.

Comment: The definition does not say anything about periodic functions, and does not require the function to be periodic. We don't know that this function is periodic. Ignore any irrelevancies about periods. Don't complicate things for yourself.

Comment: Sure but $exp(z)=1$ not only at $z=0$ so that surley has to be taken into account?

Comment: Pick a *single* singularity. Try and draw an open ball around *that* singularity, that misses any *other* singularities. Of course this means you need to have computed the entire set of singularities.